# autoprefixer-cli doesn't give an error when running, but no file is outputted

Tags: autoprefixer

I've set this up, to try and help me create CSS files for older browser:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/autoprefixer-cli

It all seems to have installed ok:

```
autoprefixer-cli -v
autoprefixer-cli 6.7.7
```

When I run it though, it seems to run through but I don't see any differences:

```
autoprefixer-cli -o /home/user/web/site.org/public_html/test-newer/css/test.css /home/user/web/site.org/public_html/test-newer/css/category.css -m -b "ie 9"
```

...and then comparing the 2 files:

```
 diff category.css test.css
3728c3728
< /*# sourceMappingURL=category.css.map */
\ No newline at end of file
---
> /*# sourceMappingURL=test.css.map */
\ No newline at end of file
```

I know it should be doing something for IE, as I have stuff like:

```
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why - but it needed to be this instead:

> last 2 IE versions

So:

```
autoprefixer-cli -o /home/user/web/site.org/public_html/test-newer/css/test.css /home/user/web/site.org/public_html/test-newer/css/category.css -m -b "last 2 IE versions"
```

Works like a charm now. This will save me so much hassle!